# Remove Stacked Plotly Graphs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have been slamming my head against this and don't know if I'm blind or there isn't an answer. I have created a script to generate 3 separate reports. I feed a function 3 separate dictionaries and get 1 report that looks great. However, the following two reports come out with the data from the previous one on top of it. Is there some way to clear a Plotly object? Below is an image with some dummy data of what I'm referring to and the code.

Here is the 1st report generated. (You can see no overlaying values or strange displays.)
[image: Original Plot with no issue]

This is the issue. (Strange overlaying of different values)
[image: 2nd Plot with the issue]

```
def createReport(myDict,name):
   for key in myDict:
      if key.__contains__("ER"):
         indirectLabels.append(key)
         indirectValues.append(round(myDict[key],2))
      else:
         directLabels.append(key)
         directValues.append(round(myDict[key],2))
   pieTotal = [round(sum(myDict.values()),2)]
   myDict['pieTotal'] = pieTotal
   myDict['indirectLabels'] = indirectLabels
   myDict['indirectValues'] = indirectValues
   myDict['directValues'] = directValues
   myDict['directLabels'] = directLabels

   fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, subplot_titles=('Total Payroll','Indirect Payroll Breakdown','Direct Payroll Breakdown'),
                                        specs=[[{"type": "pie"}, {"type": "bar"}],
                                               [{"colspan": 2}, None]])
   fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
      values=myDict['pieTotal'],
      text=myDict['pieTotal'],
      domain=dict(x=[0, 0.5])), 
      row=1, col=1)
   fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
      y=myDict['indirectValues'],
      text=myDict['indirectValues'],
      x=myDict['indirectLabels']), 
      row=1, col=2)
   fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
      y=myDict['directValues'],
      text=myDict['directValues'],
      x=myDict['directLabels']), 
      row=2, col=1)
   fig.update_layout(
      title_text="Payroll Data MTD: " + name
   )
   fig.show()
   del fig
   #fig.write_image(name+'_PayrollReport.pdf')

createReport(constructionDict,'Construction')

createReport(serviceDict,'Service')
```

Comment: Your assignment is a bit confusing. The output graph looks good. Please be more specific. And is the code in your question all code? If the subplot definition is outside the function, wouldn't putting the subplot definition inside the function solve the problem?

Comment: @r-beginners, Let me try to clarify. I've added the 1st graph that is created by the function. The 2nd photo is the 2nd report which should contain different values but seems to contain both values from the first dict, and the second dict. I originally had the subplot definition inside of the function but got the same result and thought defining the subplots differently outside of the function could remedy it.

Comment: I don't understand how you can put the definition of a subplot in a function and have the same result. Maybe someone can help if you present the code and sample data.